# Loop in Linked List error while reversing a linked list?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I'm getting a loop in linked list error while trying to reverse a linked list-

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        
        first = head
        second = head.next
        third = head.next.next
        
        while third != None and third.next != None:
            
            third = second.next
            
            second.next = first
            first = second
            second = third

            
        print(first)
        print (second)
            
        return second
```

Output : [5]

And the error is-

Error - Found cycle in the ListNode
ListNode{val: 5, next: None}

Comment: Any idea how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at:

```
third = second.next
```

'third' value does not ever change

How is the reversed list supposed to be?

Usually in a reversed Linked List the head becomes the tail, and vice versa and the next values point to the previous link

Comment: yes, it's not changing... can you please modify the code in the while block?

Comment: You can find a python algorithm to reverse a LinkedList here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/